# Why is my fstream not creating data1.txt file?

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream dataFile("data1.txt");
    if(dataFile.fail()) 
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open file"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    double value = 0;
    while(dataFile >> value)
        cout<<"Read: "<< value << endl;
    dataFile.close();
}
```

The output of this program is always Unable to open file.
please tell me why im not able to make files. im using a mac book pro (IED: coderunner 2) dont know if that makes a difrence

Comment: Try using an absolute pathname for the filename.

Comment: It's unexpected that the current folder that the IDE sets for execution would be a folder that the user does not have write permission.

Comment: *"please tell me why im not able to make files."* Instantiating an `fstream` will not create the file. An `ofstream` will create the file. This question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your IDE, the program might not be running in the location you think it is. Try putting your text file in different locations in the project hierarchy. It's likely that it's not in the right spot.

Comment: `getcwd` is also helpful in determining the working directory the IDE is using.

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify the location of the file first. For example when running your program from a VS IDE you would not place the text file inside a Debug or Release folder. You would place your text file inside a folder from which your IDE launches an executable. If you ran a standalone executable then you would place your txt file in the same folder with the executable.
[image: Fstream]
Since you are using your file for the input and not the output you could use the `std::ifstream` instead:

```
std::ifstream dataFile("data1.txt");
```

Comment: The default is `ios::in | ios::out`

Comment: @Barmar I stand corrected. I have updated the answer with relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code that *creates* a file.

To create a file:
1) Use `std::ofstream`
2) Use `std::fstream` with the correct mode.

Although not necessary, you should write data to the file to help create it.

The code in your post is *reading* from a file.  You *open* a file, and the open may not be successful.  You should have your program tell `fstream` the path to the file (to remove ambiguities).